# How to change the launch Screen on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, launch-screen

I've created an app mobile iOS using xamarin, and I would like to change the default LaunchScreen, I've created a "LaunchScreen.storyboard" on Xcode, it's just a green screen to try it. I added it to my ressources, but when I select it in info.plist launch screen, nothing happens and I still have the default launchscreen a blue screen with xamarin logo, I already clean and build, delete my app... Do you have an idea to fix that?

Info.plist:

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
```

LaunchScreen.storyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="21701" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="01J-lp-oVM">
<device id="retina6_12" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
<dependencies>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="21679"/>
    <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
    <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
    <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="EHf-IW-A2E">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="01J-lp-oVM" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Ze5-6b-2t3">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="393" height="852"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemGreenColor"/>
                </view>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="iYj-Kq-Ea1" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="53" y="375"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
<resources>
    <systemColor name="systemGreenColor">
        <color red="0.20392156862745098" green="0.7803921568627451" blue="0.34901960784313724" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
    </systemColor>
</resources>
```

Comment: I don't see anything suspicious in your setup, have you tried manually deleting the *bin* and *obj* folders before rebuilding the app (you may need to close Visual Studio for this)? Try removing the `<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>` and the value below it, that shouldn't be required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work.

Comment: 1. Consider copying the code of your new created LaunchScreen.storyboard to the default one in Resources folder. 2. What if you create a new MyStoryboard.storyboard and then set `<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>MyStoryboard</string>` in info.plist, see:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=macos#managing-launch-screens-with-storyboards

Comment: Thanks for your respond, I've deleted the default storyboard, I thought that could help and I've already tried the storyboard that I've create on Xcode, a storyboard that I've create from the link you send and a storyboard from another guy's project, none are working.

Comment: @Antoine21000 Have you followed the official docs:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=macos#managing-launch-screens-with-storyboards ?

Comment: Yes, I did follow it.